# EAS Submit updates iOS app w/o AppStore submission

Tags: expo, app-store-connect, eas

I just started using EAS for my managed react native app after the deprecation of the `expo:build` command.

Preparing my app's first update since this switch, I used EAS build to build my app, and then EAS submit to get the build onto AppStoreConnect so I could then submit the update for review to Apple. This all went as expected, and I could see the new version of my app in AppStoreConnect labeled as "Ready to Submit".

I did not submit the update for review to Apple, but the next day, all of my users reported that their apps were displaying the newest update.

AppStoreConnect confirms the build is still awaiting submission to the official AppStore, and my users do not report seeing any new update in their AppStore download history. These users are NOT affiliated with any TestFlight groups that could potentially have access to a testing version.

How is this happening??

The only commands I used during submission were:
`eas build -platform ios` and `eas submit -platform ios`

I did also at a separate point the same day use `eas device:create` to create a personal dev environment which DOES have a similar effect of having my installed version of the app display development changes without showing any actual update to the app—HOWEVER this was set up to only work with my device and needed 2-factor authentication to enable, so it doesn't make sense for this to somehow affect other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an over-the-air update via `eas update` that caused this.